# Java: QueryDsl custom column names in generated Q-classes

Tags: java, querydsl

I got an entity class

```
@Config(defaultVariableName = "t_class_entity")
@Getter 
@NoArgsConstructor 
@AllArgsConstructor 
@Entity(name = "t_class_entity") 
public class ClassEntity {     
    @Column(name = "ct_qqq")     
    private Instant qqq; 
}
```

and generated class

```
@Generated("com.querydsl.codegen.EntitySerializer") 
public class QClassEntity extends EntityPathBase<ClassEntity> {
    public final DateTimePath<java.time.Instant> qqq = createDateTime("qqq", java.time.Instant.class); 
}
```

I need to replace **qqq** in generated class to **ct_qqq**.

Our project use exactly this [way](http://querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.1.2/reference/html_single/#d0e132) (`com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor`) so I do not want to change it if there is any other approach.

Comment: Why can't you change the name of the field in the entity class?